# Alternate of C++ 's "vector <int> adj[10]" for Go Lang

Tags: c++, go, vector

I am searching for an equivalent to a *C++* `vector<int> adj[10]` in Go, where we can do the following actions:

```
adj[x].push_back(y);

sort(adj[x].begin(),adj[x].end());
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var adj [10][]int
// elements are nil by default; initialize them
// (not strictly necessary for append() to work)
for i := range adj {
  adj[i] = make([]int)
}

// code translated from C++
adj[x] = append(adj[x], y)
sort.Ints(adj[x])
```